# XML error object has no attribute 'cssselect'

Tags: python, xml, django, lxml

the following does not appear to parse the xml data correctly or is doing something wrong.

This is the code being run.

from lxml import etree
   from lxml.etree import fromstring

```
if request.POST:

    xml = request.POST['xml'].encode('utf-8')
    parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True, recover=True, encoding='utf-8')
    h = fromstring(xml, parser=parser)
    status = h.cssselect('itagg_delivery_receipt status').text_content()
    return HttpResponse(status)
```

The error:

**AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'cssselect' status**

This is the xml document that is being sent:

```
 <?xml version="1.1" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<itagg_delivery_receipt>
<version>1.0</version>
<msisdn>447889000000</msisdn>
<submission_ref>
845tgrgsehg394g3hdfhhh56445y7ts6</
submission_ref>
<status>Delivered</status>
<reason>4</reason>
<timestamp>20050709120945</timestamp>
<retry>0</retry>
</itagg_delivery_receipt>
```

I have dumped out str(h) and it looks like this  `<element 0x7fd341e93870="" at="" itagg_delivery_receipt=""></element>`

Comment: i don't think you can use cssselect on an xml doc. If you import from lxml.html you get cssselect, but i don't know if that's appropriate for your XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the thing you want with `xpath`:

```
>>> h.xpath('status/text()')
['Delivered']
```

So with a little helper function in your code:

```
def first(seq,default=None):
  for item in seq:
    return item
  return default

...

status = first(h.xpath('status/text()'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using [cssselect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect) you need to install it

```
pip install cssselect
```

Comment: There's a cssselect module in the `lxml` library the OP is using.

Comment: @MattH Just reread `csssellect.py` from lxml and found "This is a thin wrapper around cssselect 0.7 or later."

Comment: @MattH lxml added another obstacle (there's a surprise..) by removing its built-in cssselect and using an external one, meaning you have to install it separately